# How to find associations between Likert-type scale and numeric measurements?

Tags: correlation, likert

I’m trying to statistically analyze possible associations between two sets of data. One comprises of Likert-type scale data which measured the opinion of a team member regarding other members' attitudes during a collaborative project.

The other set are numeric measurements that were extracted from activity logs. 16 students worked in teams of 4 members to develop software together. They used tools capable of tracking different activities (e.g., number of modifications in files, number of messages sent to other team members via chat). I have extracted the activity logs of a 4 months period for each student.

Students peer assessed each other member of their teams twice during the project. They assessed their peers by responding to Likert questionnaire items such as ‘how communicative was the student A during this phase of the project?’ — Not at all communicative; Slightly communicative; Somewhat communicative; Very communicative; Extremely communicative.

My question is: how do I investigate possible associations between the two sets described above? My assumption is that some metrics, e.g. the number of messages sent via chat, will positively correlate with the respective peer assessment score obtained by a student regarding the quality of their communication with others, i.e. the higher the number of messages sent, the better the score of a student will be.

From the first dataset, I have around 6 aspects that were peer assessed. I mentioned communication, but we also asked students to evaluate other characteristics such as leadership, technical knowledge etc. From the second dataset, I have around 20 different metrics. All of them are numbers based on the number of times a student performed each activity within a given period of time during the project. I’m hoping that this analysis will reveal some unexpected associations between (A) characteristics that were peer assessed and (B) counts that were extracted from the activity logs.

Another related question is: each student was assessed by three other team members. I noticed some variation in the responses, which may be explained due to different opinions, but also due to social desirability bias, central tendency bias etc. Is it safe to summarize that in order to generate a single score for each student? If yes, what is the proper way to aggregate these assessments? Median? I have found different methods to do that, but this seems to be a controversial issue.

Assuming that I solved the aggregation problem, I’d have to choose a proper statistical test in order to find and analyse possible associations between the peer assessment aggregated scores and the metrics I have extracted. My goal is to recommend a set of metrics that a teacher may pay attention to when assessing different aspects of teamwork and individual performance.

What do you suggest? Which statistical tests should I perform to find and measure the strength of those associations?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have a measure of overall project success?

Your problem is really the Likert scores.  I presume this is not a validated instrument?  So your problem really is what to do about this.  I'm tempted to suggest you need to sum over the raters and shrink this towards the team's average likert profile.  But I would want to think this through.

Comment: It's not a validated instrument and I haven't defined a measure of overall project success. My issue right now is how to aggregate the peer assessment scores for each student. I'm thinking of using the median rather than averaging all the values for each Likert question.

Comment: In my opinion, the sum would work as well as any other the reviewing peers as any other statistic.  If everybody always reviews, that would be no different than the average.   Median seems likely to carry less information...it is not an aggregate statistic anyway and with only 3 scores, it seems likely to be bland in terms of information.  But I have not thought that through.  The problem with Likert scores is not so much their lack of continuity as it is their lack of fixed origin.  People tend to answer in the middle as much because they don't care as because they do.

Comment: Thanks StatNoodle. I did two peer reviews with students (one for each project sprint), so that each student has six scores. I would add them, but there is a group with only 5 scores for each student, because one student didn't answer the peer assessment. I'll use both median and mean and see what I get.

Comment: The median carries less information on one hand, but on the other hand it tends to favor the opinion of the group majority -- I noticed that some scores are skewed, with quite conflicting opinions among team members. The median also attenuates some forms of bias (e.g. central tendency). What do you think? Also, which type of correlation should I use (Spearman, Pearson)? To analyze correlations, do you have any suggestion as to which form of visualization would be appropriate? I'm thinking of plotting everything into a correlation matrix.